# My 'if' statement is not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an assignment where I am supposed to determine whether the average of three values is 'above average' or 'below average'. For some reason whatever is input will always be above average as the result. Here is my code below, thank you for any help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lesson_12_Activity_One {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter three values");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        double y = scan.nextDouble();
        double z = scan.nextDouble();
        double t = (double)Math.round(100*((x+y+z)/3));

        System.out.print("The average is " + (t/100));

        if(t >= 89.5)     
            System.out.print(" ABOVE AVERAGE");
        else
            System.out.print(" BELOW AVERAGE");    
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share some input values that you tried? where the expected result was Below Average?

Comment: Maybe it's always above 89.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The average is `t/100` but in your condition you test if `t > 89.5` (which is always true since `t` is the average multiplied by 100).

Just remove both the multiplication by 100 and the division by 100. They don't seem necessary.

```
double t = Math.round((x+y+z)/3);

System.out.print("The average is " + t);

if(t >= 89.5)     
    System.out.print(" ABOVE AVERAGE");
else
    System.out.print(" BELOW AVERAGE");    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to coding in general so I mess up a lot when rounding a number to a certain place.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(t/100 >= 89.5)     
   System.out.print(" ABOVE AVERAGE");
 else
   System.out.print(" BELOW AVERAGE");
```

by the way why are you multiplying and then dividing by 100?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna guess that you're mixing up perunages and percentages. That means, at one point in your program you use 0.5 and in the other 50, both as 50%.

```
    double t = (double)Math.round(100*((x+y+z)/3));

    System.out.print("The average is " + (t/100));
```

With x, y and z all as 50, this will output 50. `t = 100 * (50 + 50 + 50)/3 = 5000`, the output is `(t/100) = 50`.

`if(t >= 89.5)` however tests with `t = 5000`.
To solve this, go down one of two paths.

1. Replace all percentages for perunages. This means inputting numbers from 0 to 1.
   To do this, do the following:
   change your t-initialization for `double t = (double)Math.round(1000*((x+y+z)/3)) / 1000` This will make T be in between 0 and 1 with 3 digits precision.
   Replace your `if` with `if (t >= 0.895)`
2. Replace all perunages with percentages. This means inputting numbers from 0 to 100.
   To do this, remove the 100* from your `double t = (double)Math.round(100*((x+y+z)/3));`, and the /100 from the output message.